# Can not find angular/core, angular-router-deprecated module in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

[image]

And It also showing Can not find name 'Map','Promise'.Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `@` in front of `angular` (RC versions of Angular2):

```
import { ... } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: but still i am getting this issue after adding @ :)

Comment: Which version of Angular2 do you use? There is package renaming in RC version. In beta versions, it's `angular2/core`...

Comment: I am using beta version.When I use
import {Component} from "angular2/core"; then Its working fine :)

Comment: So use `import { ... } from 'angular2/core';`

Comment: Thanks!! Its worked for angular/core but I am Still stuck with angular-router-deprecated :(

Comment: You're welcome! With beta versions, it's `import { ... } from 'angular2/router';`

Comment: Do you have any Idea for "Can not find name 'Map','Promise' " ? :)

Comment: I think that it's a problem of typings. You could define a typings.json file and add es6-shim in it. See this page for more details: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/typescript-configuration.html#!#typings